# Removing a listview item by string

Tags: c#, listview

I've got a `Listview`, in which I add all clients connected.

How would I remove a client from the `Listview`, when I only know the name?

To add a client to the `Listview` I use this code:

```
public void AddToClientList(string ClientName)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { listView1.Items.Add(ClientName); });
    else
        listView1.Items.Add(ClientName);
}
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to remove:

```
public void RemoveFromClientList(string ClientName)
{
    if (InvokeRequired){
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { listView1.Items.Remove(ClientName); });
    }
    else{
        listView1.Items.Remove(ClientName);
}}
```

I get this error on the `listview1.items.remove(clientname)`:

> ListView.ListViewItemCoIIection ListView.Items  Gets a collection
>   containing all items in the control.  Error:  The best overloaded
>   method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCoIIection.Remove(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Here's the error
http://gyazo.com/3fe429b1dec07c94b998f5c8f0d11f66

Comment: Please include the error in the question. If you are going to ask random strangers on the internet for help, it's kind of nice if you don't force them to view additional detail on an external site. Also if that sire ever goes down the question becomes useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void RemoveFromClientList(string ClientName)
{
    ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
    listviewitem .Name = ClientName;
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { listView1.Items.Remove(listviewitem ); });
    }
    else{
            listView1.Items.Remove(listviewitem );
    }
}
```

**Edits 1:**

```
public ListViewItem GetItemtoDelete(string ClientName )
{
       ListViewItem listviewitem=new ListViewItem();
       for (int i=0;i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            listviewitem=listView1.Items[i];
            if (ClientName == listviewitem.Text)
             {
                  return listviewitem;
             }
        }
       return null;
}


public void RemoveFromClientList(string ClientName)
{
    ListViewItem listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
    listviewitem =GetItemtoDelete(ClientName );
    if(listviewitem !=null)
    {
         if (InvokeRequired)
         {
               Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { listView1.Items.Remove(listviewitem ); });
         }
         else
         {
               listView1.Items.Remove(listviewitem );
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Qube : Where do you call your RemoveClientList in your code behind ?

Comment: true because I forget to add listView1.Refresh(); after deleting

Comment: @christof13 Here's my code behind:

   void Chatserver_OnClientDisconnected(object Sender, DisconnectedArguments R)
        {
            
            clients = clients - 1;
            RemoveFromClientList(R.Name);
            
            
        }

Comment: @Qube try to add listView1.Refresh(); after deleting and retest your program

Comment: @FerasSalim Now i've created a RefreshListView with this code:
   if(InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { listView1.Refresh(); });
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Refresh();
            }
and i've tried calling this function after deletion but nothing happens.
Why do i need to refresh when deleting when i dont need to refresh when adding?

Comment: it forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child control, in adding this happen automatically

Comment: @FerasSalim Ohh ok, anyways thanks for the help.
It still doesn't work but i guess i'll have to drop it :/

Comment: @FerasSalim New error :P
http://gyazo.com/69ad119b92ec5abb47cf1626bf69a6e3
Edit:
It's wpf if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RemoveByKey` instead of `Remove`.

The reason being that you are adding the item, using a method that creates an item automatically, based on your string provided.

Using remove, you need to specify which item, and not which string that was used to name the item.

In the case of RemoveByKey, the key is the name used, which can be resolved as the same name used to add/create the list item.

See more:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removebykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Remove method accept a listViewItem as parameter not a string. You have to find the listItem before calling the Remove method

```
 public void RemoveFromClientList(string ClientName)
{

        var toRemove =listView1.Items.Find(ClientName);
        if (toRemove != null)
        {
           listView1.Items.Remove(toRemove);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work but this is the code I used to remove temp files from showing up in my listView.

```
if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                string delete = "~$";
                if (item.Text.Contains(delete))
                {
                    listView1.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
```